# Unity Hub not letting me use a version I installed

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

[image]

I'm trying to use 2020.3.25f1 that I installed, but it won't let me use it when creating a new project, and when I try to add it, it says it's already here. So it looks like it knows it's here but won't let me use it?

Comment: Your screenshot shows a newer version of Unity Hub is available, so try updating to the latest Hub first. If that doesn’t solve the problem, try uninstalling and reinstalling the editor version that’s not working maybe?

Comment: @SvenViking Before I read your comment, that's what I ended up doing, and that solved it! So you were right on the money!

Answer (score 0):

Install 2020.3.25f1 version completely. Once you are done with installation. Go to projects tabs NEW button on right most click on the small down arrow , and select version you want to create project in which.